# Unable to get User pointer from a Class in Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Class on Parse called "OnlineUsers" (screenshot below). One of the fields is "user", which is a pointer to a user in the "User" table. My issue is that I cannot get the "User" pointer from the "OnlineUsers" class "users" field/object.

[image]

The "user" field is a pointer to the a user in the "User" Class. I am saving the data alright because when I click on the "user" field in class "OnlineUsers", i get taken to the Users class entry on Parse's web browser (see below).

[image]

Now I am trying to get "user" field object from "OnlineUsers" class in the code below. I have put the error also below.

```
func printobJectIdsWithoutMe() {
    let usersToPrint = PFQuery(className: "OnlineUsers")

    usersToPrint.whereKey("user", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    usersToPrint.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if results!.count > 0 {
                println("launchChatwithRandomUser() -- There are more than zero objects in Class, results.count = " + String(results!.count))

                let usersOnlineNow = results as! [PFObject]

                for user in usersOnlineNow {
                    //println(user["user"]!.objectId)
                    let userObject:PFUser = user["user"]as! PFUser
                    println(userObject.username!)  //THIS NEVER PRINTS
                }

            } else {
                println("launchChatwithRandomUser() -- There are ZERO objects in Class, results.count = " + String(results!.count))

            }
        } else {
            println("failed with error in usersToPrint.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock")
        }

    })

}
```

The output of the println statements are as below (note only one gets printed):

`launchChatwithRandomUser() -- There are more than zero objects in Class, results.count = 2`

***Question is***: Why does this never print anything?
`println(userObject.username!)`  //THIS NEVER PRINTS

Comment: Does it cause out of bounds error? Try removing +1 from randomNumber. Maybe, thats causing issue.  Suppose, you have 5 objects, so, random number should be between 0 to 4 and not 1 to 5 if ou wanna use it as index in results array. Let me know if it works

Comment: hey -- i dont think it's the random number, i have something more basic wrong. I updated with a more simple. I am just not able to get the user object. See my example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. The trick is to use PFQuery includeKey to have the related pointer data automatically filled by Parse. The user data will be downloaded without requiring you to make another query for it.

```
let usersToPrint = PFQuery(className: "OnlineUsers")    
query.includeKey("User")
```

Try adding this line. Hope it helps... :)

Comment: aah, perfect. You are absolutely right... I was missing the `includeKey`. Thank you.